# VmWare Workstation 9

Tags: vmware

Guys im having problem with changing the license key of VmWare Workstation 9 on ubuntu. The terminal commands i found doesnt work neither which gives me the error saying that no such location found. I use Ubuntu 13.04 so where did VmWare installed and how can I change it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the key, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx-debug --new-sn 12345-abcde-67890-fghij-1a2b3
```

The key in the command is not functional, replace with your own key

Also try this.  Start VMWare as root

```
sudo -i
```

type your password

```
vmware
```

**Note**: its not necessary to run VMWare as root for any other reason.  This is only needed when changing or adding a license key.

Comment: Nope unfortunately it doesnt work. No directory found ! How can I find in which directory VmWare installed ?

Comment: I missed the first `/`.  See if that works now.

Comment: Would you please let me know if it works :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked:)